# Task.Delay in .net fires 125ms early

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, task

So I'm having a really strange behavior with a c# task delay that is kind of making me insane.

*Context:* I'm using C# .net to communicate with one of our devices via R4852. The device needs roughly 200ms to finish each command so I introduced a 250ms delay inside my communication class.

*Bug / bad behavior:* The delay inside my communication class sometimes waits for 250ms and sometimes only waits for 125ms. This is reproducible and the same behavior occurs when I'm increasing my delay. E.g. if I set my delay to 1000ms every second request will only wait for 875ms, so again there are 125ms missing.
This behavior only occurs if there is no debugger attached and only occurs on some machines. The machine where this software will be used in our production department is having this issue, my machine that I'm working on right now doesn't have this issue. Both are running Windows 10.

**How come that there are 125ms missing from time to time?** 
I already learnt that the Task.Delay method is using a timer with a precision of 15ms. This doesn't explain the missing 125ms as it at most should fire a few milliseconds too late instead of 125m too early.

The following method is the one I use to queue commands to my device. There is a semaphore responsible so that only one command can be executed at a time (_requestSemapohre) so there can only ever be one request being processed.

```cs
public async Task<bool> Request(WriteRequest request)
{
    await _requestSemaphore.WaitAsync();    // block incoming calls
    await Task.Delay(Delay);                // delay
    Write(_connectionIdDictionary[request.Connection], request.Request);           // write
    if (request is WriteReadRequest)
    {
        _currentRequest = request as WriteReadRequest;
        var readSuccess = await _readSemaphore.WaitAsync(Timeout); // wait until read of line has finished
        _currentRequest = null;                 // set _currentRequest to null
        _requestSemaphore.Release();            // release next incoming call
        if (!readSuccess)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (request is WriteWithDelayRequest)
        {
            await Task.Delay((request as WriteWithDelayRequest).Delay);
        }
        _requestSemaphore.Release();            // release next incoming call
        return true;
    }
}
```

The following code is part of the method that is sending the requests to the method above. I removed some lines to keep it short. The basic stuff (requesting and waiting) is still there

```cs
// this command is the first command and will always have a proper delay of 1000ms
var request = new Communication.Requests.WriteRequest(item.Connection, item.Command);
await _translator.Request(request);

// this request is the second request that is missing 125ms
var queryRequest = new Communication.Requests.WriteReadRequest(item.Connection, item.Query);    // query that is being sent to check if the value has been sent properly
if (await _translator.Request(queryRequest))    // send the query to the device and wait for response
{
    if (item.IsQueryValid(queryRequest.Response))   // check result
    {
        item.Success = true;
    }
}
```

The first request that I'm sending to this method is a `WriteRequest`, the second one a `WriteReadRequest`.

I discovered this behavior when looking at the serial port communication using a software named *Device Monitoring Studio* to monitor the serial communication.

Here is a screenshot of the actual serial communication. In this case I was using a delay of 1000ms. You can see that the `sens0002` command had a delay of exactly 1 second before it was executed. The next command / query `sens?`only has a 875ms delay. This screenshot was taken while the debugger was not attached.
[image: Screenshot showing the bug with 1000ms delay]

Here is another screenshot. The delay was set to 1000ms again but this time the debugger was attached. As you can see the first and second command now both have a delay of roughly 1000ms.
[image: Screenshot showing 1000ms delay as debugger is attached]

And in the two following screenshots you can see the same behavior with a delay of 250ms (bugged down to 125ms). First screenshot without debugger attached, second one with debugger attached. In the second screenshot you can also see that there is quiet the drift of 35ms but still nowhere close to the 125ms that were missing before.
[image: Screenshot showing the bug with 250ms delay]
[image]

So what the hell am I looking at here? The quick and dirty solution would be to just increase the delay to 1000ms so that this won't be an issue anymore but I'd rather understand why this issue occurs and how to fix it properly.

Cheers!

Comment: stupid question - why don't you `Thread.Sleep` instead?

Comment: @zaitsman That would block the main thread and is not recommended

Comment: Also, it is unclear what is calling your `Request()` method so it may have something to do with it

Comment: Thread swapping can cause such delays - the timer won't fire if the thread isn't running. Also explains why `Thread.Sleep` will result in far worse skew

Comment: @SouvikGhosh No it wouldn't, if the whole thing is wrapped into a `Thread` or `Task.Run`

Comment: @zaitsman yes, it would introduce a huge delay as the CPU dumped the thread and all it data, picked up a *different* thread to run and after at least the sleep time put the thread back in the OS scheduler's queue, to be eventually executed. At which time all the stack, data would have to be reloaded into the CPU. That's why `Thread.Sleep` isn't a good idea

Comment: @zaitsman The second block of code is showing the part of the method that is calling the `Request` method (`await _translator.Request(...);`). The request classes only contain the command (string) and if it's a `WriteReadRequest` the response from the device

Comment: I think you can use a stopwatch with a while loop. Just break from the while loop when the time elapses. This won't block the main thread or any thread swapping/switching I guess.

Comment: @Fildor em, that guy basically says 'if on main thread, use `ConfigureAwait()`' in fig. 5. Am aware of this. But if you wrap all of the async calls in `Task.Run(async () => await whatever());` then the calling thread (main thread in your GUI or asp.net app) may continue

Comment: @Fildor in both cases Stephen is doing `Task.Wait()`. Why would you wait a task if you wanted the code to complete? that makes no sense. the only time you would put `async` inside `Task.Run` is if you DON'T want to wait.

Comment: @Fildor the way i would do the code in this question:

`var request = new Communication.Requests.WriteRequest(item.Connection, item.Command);
Task.Run(async () => {
await _translator.Request(request);

var queryRequest = new Communication.Requests.WriteReadRequest(item.Connection, item.Query);    
if (await _translator.Request(queryRequest))    // send the query to the device and wait for response
{
    if (item.IsQueryValid(queryRequest.Response))   // check result
    {
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {item.Success = true; }));    
    }
}});`

Comment: And inside the `_translator.Request()` we could use Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @Fildor I agree. You're not helping, your discussing about different paradigms of programming and that is not the question I asked.

Comment: Also, I'd rather not change the async nature of my class(es). I'm very happy on how it performes, how the code looks and operates. I might have an issue with Task.Delay but this certainly won't make me change my architecture. 
The only proper response to my question yet was by @SouvikGhosh. Creating my own timer that will be more precise was something that I wanted to avoid but I already thought of that solution. This still would only make me fix the issue but not understand the cause of the issue in the first place.

Comment: @KollmannMichael Yes, sorry 'bout that. I just think using Thread.Sleep is bad advice for *you* ... - but that would be all the help to draw from that.

Comment: _"The machine where this software will be used in our production department is having this issue, my machine that I'm working on right now doesn't have this issue."_ - Are both machines running the (exact) same .net Runtime version?

Comment: The machine in our production department only has .net 4.7 installed, on my machine there is .net 4.7 and also the target SDKs for 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6 and 4.6.1. My application targets 4.6.1

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, your times are printed as delta to the prev. entry.

In case of the 125/875ms you have 8 intermediate entries with each roughly 15ms (sum roughly 120ms)

In case of 250/1000ms you have 8 intermediate entries with each roughly 5ms (sum roughly 40ms) and the numbers are actually more like 215/960ms.

So, if you add those intermediate delays, the resulting complete delay is roughly the same as far as I can tell.

---

Answering the question for everyone who just wants a **yes / no** on the question title: [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

It's save to assume, that `Task.Delay` covers at least the specified amount of time (might be more due to clock resolution). So if it seems to cover a smaller timespan, then the method used to test the actual delay is faulty somehow.

Comment: @KollmannMichael In response to "the 15ms are the character transfers" (or something similar that you commented): does `Write(_connectionIdDictionary[request.Connection], request.Request)` block execution until all characters are written or does it just fill a buffer and return?

Comment: I think you're on to something here. I'll get back to you when I get the chance to look at my code when I'm back at work

Comment: The timing is affected by the OS clock interrupt rate.  15.625 msec is the normal rate, 5 msec is not.  But tends to happen when running the program at the same time as a music player or web browser.  The underlying winapi function that allows changing the rate is [timeBeginPeriod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx).  Being able to send only one character per clock tick is not healthy and should be fixed.